# Proof of inequality in probability theroy using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

The domain of random variable $X$ is the set of nonnegative integers. (*We assume that all sums are well-defined.*)

I do not understand why the following inequality holds (or not) $$\bigg( \sum_{i=1}^\infty i \cdot Pr[X=i] \bigg)^2 \leq \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^\infty i^2 \cdot Pr[X=i] \bigg) \bigg( \sum_{i=1} Pr[X=i] \bigg). \quad\quad (*)$$

I apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality on the left-hand side of $(*)$ to obtain $$\bigg( \sum_{i=1}^\infty i \cdot Pr[X=i] \bigg)^2 \leq \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^\infty i^2 \bigg) \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^\infty Pr[X=i]^2 \bigg).$$

Now, the problem is reduced to show $$\bigg( \sum_{i=1}^\infty i^2 \bigg) \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^\infty Pr[X=i]^2 \bigg) \leq \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^\infty i^2 \cdot Pr[X=i] \bigg) \bigg( \sum_{i=1} Pr[X=i] \bigg).$$

I try to figure it out why this is true but with no success. Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to apply Cauchy-Schwartz a bit differently the first time round. You have decomposed $i \cdot P[X=i]$ as $i$ times $P[X = i]$. Try writing it as $i \cdot P[X=i]^{\frac12}$ times $P[X=i]^{\frac12}$ and apply Cauchy-Schwartz.

Comment: Thank you, It makes sense now.